# How does Poppy relate to the Merlaut job?

Tags: watch-dogs

This question contains spoilers.  I'd recommend not reading it until you've finished the game.

> Towards the middle of the game, you meet Poppy, the nude sex-slave who tries to stab Aiden.
>
>  [image: Poppy stabbing Aiden]
>
>  You save her and her fellow sex-slaves, then she is never mentioned again.
>
>  However, upon rewatching the intro I noticed **she was in the hotel during the Merlaut job (!!)**, wearing a trenchcoat and playing with her cell-phone *(which in this game basically equates to being a hacker)*
>
>  [image: Poppy the hacker]
>  [image]
>
>  Whoa, what!?  I thought the other hacker was Iraq!? And I don't remember there being any mention of Poppy being a hacker.

What's going on here!?  Did I miss a subtle clue somewhere?  Or is this explained in one of the *(many)* DLC I don't have or audio logs I missed?

Comment: JFYI - The Merlaut is a hotel, not a bank.

Comment: Also: It could be that she just walks "home" from another "job".

Comment: @5pike: Who says she was a prostitute?  Being sold as a sex-slave isn't typically something someone does by choice.

Comment: That's just one likely scenario. She could have been just a normal visitor. I think they missed a great opportunity for a plot twist.

Comment: @5pike This was way too deliberate to just be a coincidence

Comment: Well, I think it's just coincidence/missed opportunity. There might be an explanation in an audio-log or sidequest. Let's wait and see what someone might dig up.

Comment: I was sure that she was somehow in cahoots with Aiden/Brenks - watch the opening scene again. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39ofIfLeQ08 between 0:15 & 0:25. There's a glitch-in-the-matrix as she bumps into Aiden and I was sure that she palmed the phone off to him. The camera follows her all the way across the hotel lobby as aiden approaches.

Comment: this needs a bounty :-) it's been driving me nuts since I read it.

Comment: @EoinCampbell When Aiden and Poppy meet in the sex club, she doesn't recognize him and believes he is the man whose identity he assumed. That makes a previous connection to Aiden unlikely.

Comment: indeed. And I went back and rewatched the intro scene a couple of times. the "Poppy" in the merlaut doesn't have her signature nose/ear chain. I'm half thinking it was some lazy model re-use and completely unconnected :-(

Comment: It might be possible that she was involved in the Merlot heist without knowing Aiden. Maybe she was ordered to slip the cellphone to "the man with the cap" and nothing more. Considering that she is enslaved by a crime syndicate, this might not even be the strangest assignment she ever got, so she might not even remember Aiden. But Aiden remembers her. That would also explain why Aiden suddenly has an emotional connection to her after the incident in the sex club.

Comment: Aiden was in the Merlaut as the "point of connection" for Damien, Poppy is probably the same, but for Iraq